# How to specify directory or file glob as javac classpath value with Apache Ant?

Tags: java, ant, javac

Is there a way to set the value of the `javac` `classpath` property in Apache Ant (v1.9.6) so that I don't have to literally specify all the jars that I want to include e.g. a directory or file glob.

So, if I have something like:

```
<javac classpath="./lib/one.jar":./lib/two.jar:./lib/three.jar..."
```

...is there anyway to just specify my `./lib` directory once, like the way you can do when you run a java application like:

```
java -cp ./lib/'*'
```

I've tried that, and just using `./lib`, or`./lib/*` or `./lib/*.jar` but they don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And another solution using a reusable classpath reference:

```
<path id="compile.path">
  <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>

<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" includeantruntime="false" debug="true" classpathref="compile.path"/>

<junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
  <classpath>
    <path refid="compile.path"/>
    <pathelement path="${classes.dir}"/>
  </classpath>
  ..
  ..
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a [`<classpath>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path) element under `<javac>`:

```
<javac ...>
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</javac>
```